# Facebook permissions and user data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-permissions

Facebook used to let me see who had commented on or liked a page, and to grab that profile information (I even built a dataset based on the names of people who had done this for a particular page I was administering) through **Graph Api**.

All of a sudden (well, really about 2 months ago), Facebook won't let me do that anymore, and I can't figure out why. I've searched for a while, and figured this would be a good stack overflow question. Do I need a premium account or something? I'm not using that much data, so they're probably not throttling me.

Comment: Why do you need to know who liked or commented on your page?

Comment: You’re most likely experiencing the effect of what is described here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.11#gapi-90-pages - you now need a page access token for the page in question to be able to get user data.